# bash script: how to use array element in if statement

Tags: bash

The simplest script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=("abc" "bcd" "cde")
 
if ${myaaray[0]} = "abc" ;
then
 echo "abc"
fi
```

I receive:

```
./a.sh: line 5: =: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a typo. `${myaaray[0]}` should be `${myarray[0]}`. It's expanded as empty and then reads as

```
if = "abc"
```

to the shell, hence the error since there is no command named `=`.
Also, the semicolon is a useless null statement and can be removed. You only need it if you place the `then` on the same line:

```
if command; then
   do_something
fi
```

Anyway, you also need to tell the shell you want a string comparison, usually with the `test` utility.

```
if test "${myarray[0]}" = "abc"; then
    echo "abc"
fi
```

If you need to perform a set of tests on strings, maybe the `case` command is useful:

```
case "${myarray[0]}" in
(abc)   echo "Start of the alphabet";;
(xyz)   echo "End of the alphabet";;
(*)     echo "Somewhere else";;
esac
```

Comment: In Bash you would generally prefer `[[` over `[` aka `test`

Comment: @tripleee I'm in favor of using non-bashisms when they are not needed. But yes, `[[` is an alternative avoiding some of the idiosyncrasies of `test`.

Comment: If you are using arrays anyway, trying to comply with POSIX in other parts is just weird. `[[` has some clear benefits in error handling and freedom from legacy behaviors from the Bourne shell. But sure, just commenting.